# Как считать строковое значение в массив в с++?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Нужно считать строковое значение с `RichTextBox` в массив. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно эти строки (что-то типа матрицы смежности) добавить в массив:

```
int GM[n][n] = {
    {0, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 0},
    {1, 0, 0, 1},
    {0, 0, 1, 0},
};
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Читаем строки из `RichTextBox` с помощью свойства [`Lines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1);
2. Разделяем каждую строку на подстроки по запятой через [`String::Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);
3. Переводим каждую подстроку в число, например через [`StringToInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300452%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);
4. Записываем числа в массив в соответствии с индексами.