# Как считать данные с richTextBox и поместить их в массив?

Tags: c++, массивы, winforms

Всем привет.

Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь ввел матрицу смежности в richTextBox и при обработке введенных данных такой текст

```
0, 1, 1, 0
0, 0, 1, 1
1, 0, 0, 1
0, 1, 0, 0
```

преобразовался в массив

```
int GM[n][n] =
{
{0, 1, 1, 0},
{0, 0, 1, 1},
{1, 0, 0, 1},
{0, 1, 0, 0}
};
```

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Повтор http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/524356/176217

Comment: так и есть, я тут более понятно объяснил что мне нужно. Или можно как то изменять вопрос?

Comment: можно. Есть кнопки/ссылки под вопросом соответствующие.

Comment: Вам же там дали ответ.